# Block video recording during execution of flutter app

Tags: flutter, youtube-player-flutter

I have a flutter application which uses `youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+7` to play YouTube videos. This is an educational app and I don't want anyone to record my video lectures through any screen recorder. Is there anything I can do to block users recording my videos? Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `FLAG_SECURE` which will prevent the screenshot and video recording.

```
 await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

This an example of how to [disable Screenshot and Video Capture](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-disable-screenshot-and-video-capture) and also see this [video](https://youtu.be/yil6EE2Fivo).

Also, if you face a problem and if it is not working in the current version, I will recommend you to read the discussion on GitHub about the  [FLAG_SECURE don't work on Flutter application](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47557)